# HTML.BeginForm doesn't call the proper action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a this part in Edit.chtml looks like

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<article class="SearchBoxCon clearfix">
                        @if (Model.Entity.Document == null)
                        {
                            using (Html.BeginForm("AudioUpload", "Noun", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", NounId = Model.Entity.Id }))
                            {
                                <article class="BtnCon">

                                    <article class="BrowseBtn">
                                        <input type="file" value="Browse" name="file">
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="BrowseUpload">
                                        <input type="submit" id="AudioUpload" value="AudioUpload">
                                    </article>

                                </article>


                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <article class="inputBTn">
                                <input type="submit" value="Play">
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
                            </article>
                        }
                    </article>

                <article class="inputBTn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </article>
                <!-- submit btn ends here -->
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Noun/Index", null, new { @class = "BackList" })
            </article>


}
```

after browsing and upload the file , and click the upload it fire the edit posting action instead of the uploadaudio which looks like

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AudioUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file , int NounId )
        {
```

Comment: is there another form in your view? for example `else {...}` after `if` ?

Comment: there's the main form of edit @using (@Html.BeginForm()) , which contains all the fields

Comment: so, Model.Entity.Document is not null...

Comment: your codes work correct. Your condition logic is incorrect...

Comment: I modified the question to show the big picture

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms

Comment: [ActionName("Edit")] put attribute on your action method it will work

Comment: Also, your beginform method is incorrect, too. You used incorrect overload method. it should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("AudioUpload", "Noun", new { NounId = Model.Entity.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", NounId = Model.Entity.Id }))`

Comment: from within form is not allowed...it will create isssues

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how to handel that I mean I need to upload file

Comment: you can two forms if required but not nested

Comment: Solved using 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149116/mvc-how-to-post-file-upload-and-other-form-fields-to-one-action

Answer (score 0):

[ActionName("Edit")] put attribute on your action method it will work

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    public ActionResult AudioUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file , int NounId )
    {
```

make you code like this if your view name is Edit.cshtml

Comment: The current request for action 'Edit' on controller type 'NounController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AudioUpload(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase, Int32) on type ArabicELearning.Controllers.NounController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection) on type ArabicELearning.Controllers.NounController

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
@if (Model.Entity.Document == null)
 {
  using (Html.BeginForm("AudioUpload", "Noun", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", NounId = Model.Entity.Id,Id="frmAudioUpload" }))
  {<article class="BtnCon">

    <article class="BrowseBtn">
    <input type="file" value="Browse" name="file">
    </article>
    <article class="BrowseUpload">
    <input type="button" id="AudioUpload" value="AudioUpload">
    </article>

    </article>
}}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#AudioUpload').click(function(){
        $('#frmAudioUpload').submit();
      });
    });
</script>
```