# dont call Action Post in mvc when use enctype

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my project I have View Like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.Sys.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Admin.Sys.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{...}
```

And My actions Are :

```
 [HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {...}
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(EditSysInfo sysInfoViewModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {}
```

in View I have :

```
 <input type="file" name="file"/> ... submit button
```

but when Click On the submit button dont cann Post action , and redirect to 
httpget Action . yesterday its work fine . I dont know why doesnt run ?
Today I just Install `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`  .
when Change to this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Its work fine , but cant post file to action this way .

I try to getting file in Action Like This :

```
HttpPostedFileBase logo = Request.Files.Get("file");
```

Allways Count `Request.Files` is `Zero`.

thanks .
**Updated:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public  ActionResult Index(EditSysInfo sysInfoViewModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {...}
```

and In View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Admin.SysInfo.ActionNames.Index, MVC.Admin.SysInfo.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
         <input type="file" name="file"/>
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149116/mvc-how-to-post-file-upload-and-other-form-fields-to-one-action

Comment: no, it doesn't work . when add `enctype ...` dont call action post. I dont know

Comment: Try giving the name Index like "Index" and add a verb to that method as [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] and remove the virtual keyword from that method and try

Comment: T4MVC automaticy Add `virtual` to all Action Methods and if I remove `virtual` I cant Access this methods by T4MVC.

Comment: In other form I can upload file bu same code , and i dont why doesn't work in this form

Comment: can you share your view code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96634/discussion-between-girish-sakhare-and-psar-tak).

Comment: @GirishSakhare please see  Updated

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, `BeginForm` helper method is not able to properly generate the form tag with the action attribute value. It could be because the parameters you provided are not valid.

Try passing the action name and controller name as strings.

The below code should work fine.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                                new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input type="file" name="file"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Assuming your `Index` action method in `HomeController`. Update the second parameter if your controller name is different.